# Размер GLsizei в OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Почему в OpenGL тип `GLsizei` имеет 32 бита? Информация отсюда: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Type

А что если система 64-битная а мне нужно хранить размер больше чем может дать 32 бита?

Comment: Уточните, где вам может понадобиться передавать размер более 2 миллиардов?

Comment: Пока мне это не понадобилось нигде. Это чисто спортивный интерес. Или это из той же оперы где 640 кб хватит всем?

Comment: Ну смотри, всегда же идет компромисс между аппетитами и возможностями. Зачем иметь размеры для чего-либо, если под столько элементов памяти даже нет? Инт64 будет всегда полупустой. Плюс, если мы размер начинаем поддерживать, то и индексация бужет нужна инт64, а это еще большие траты впустую.